# In IntelliJ IDEA, how do I make a Tomcat Server's "Peform on 'Update' action" option sticky?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a Tomcat Server running as a saved configuration in IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.3. I've saved the "Peform on 'Update' action" option to "Update classes and resources".

However, whenever I restart IntelliJ, it reverts to "Restart server", which is a huge pain since I'm just updating static files.

Is there a way to make it truly sticky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to IDEA 10.5 or 10.5.1 RC. This option should be sticky by design and I can't reproduce this issue with the latest IDEA version.

Also verify that your Tomcat Run/Debug configuration is **Saved** (persistent), otherwise a new configuration would be created every time (you can also edit the default settings for the new configurations under **Defaults** node):

[image: Tomcat]